# DAX calculation between parameter & and a table field

Tags: powerbi, dax

I got a table with a field called PERCENT. it holds the % value for each item category.
Then, I have another calculation parameter to calculate the percentage of QTy of "SD" out of Total Qty.
Now I need to add a new column to show the difference between PERCENT - the percentage of QTy.

I tried below DAX,

```
NEW2 = 
VAR V1 =
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(PO_POOPEND[ORDER_QTY]),
FILTER(
        AP_APCATGRY,
             AP_APCATGRY[APCATGRY CODE] = "LC"
     )
    )

VAR V2 =
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(PO_POOPEND[ORDER_QTY])

 )

 VAR v3 = calculate (V1/V2 *100)

var v4 = SUMX(AP_MATCAT,AP_MATCAT[PERCENT] - [NEW])
 VAR RESULT = v4
 RETURN
 RESULT
```

is it correct? Can someone help me with this

Comment: Where's the [markdown sample data](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator) and your expected result?

Comment: To add to @Peter, since you already have a working measure, could you show the actual results vs. the expected?

Comment: Please withdraw your question if you are not ready to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your DAX is unnecessarily complicated. Since you're not making use of any of the temporary variables v1, v2 or v3 it can be simplified to:

```
NEW2 =
SUMX (
    AP_MATCAT,
    AP_MATCAT[PERCENT] - [NEW]
)
```

But where does measure [NEW] come from?